# How to count number of repeated keys in several dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, count, key

Let's say I have huge number of dictionaries (it could be 10'000 dictionaries). I would like to count number of each key in all dictionaries. I.e. if I have 3 dictionaries:

- `{1: 'url1', 3: 'url2', 7: 'url3', 5: 'url4'}`
- `{1: 'url1', 7: 'url3'}`
- `{5: 'url4', 10: 'url5'}`

Then in result I should get `{1: [2, 'url1'], 10: [1, 'url5'], 3: [1, 'url2'], 5: [2, 'url4'], 7: [2, 'url3']}`.

I came to the following code:

```
lists = [{1: 'url1', 3: 'url2', 7: 'url3', 5: 'url4'}, {1: 'url1', 7: 'url3'}, {5: 'url4', 10: 'url5'}]
result = {}
for l in lists:
    for i in l:
        if i in result:
            result[i][0] += 1
        else:
            result[i] = [1, l[i]]
```

Is the any better (faster) way to do it?

Comment: Your example dictionaries all have equal values for equal keys. That is `dict1[1] == dict2[1]`. Will that be true for your huge number of dictionaries?

Comment: @Robᵩ, yes, for each equal key value will be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can accept slightly different output, this might work for you:

```
from collections import Counter

dicts = [
    {1: 'url1', 3: 'url2', 7: 'url3', 5: 'url4'},
    {1: 'url1', 7: 'url3'},
    {5: 'url4', 10: 'url5'},
]

result = Counter()
for d in dicts:
    result.update(d.keys())

print dict(result)
```

Note that has keys and counts, but no values.

Alternatively:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

dicts = [
    {1: 'url1', 3: 'url2', 7: 'url3', 5: 'url4'},
    {1: 'url1', 7: 'url3'},
    {5: 'url4', 10: 'url5'},
]

result = Counter(chain.from_iterable(dicts))

print dict(result)
```

Final version: this one produces exactly your requested output:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

dicts = [
    {1: 'url1', 3: 'url2', 7: 'url3', 5: 'url4'},
    {1: 'url1', 7: 'url3'},
    {5: 'url4', 10: 'url5'},
]

result = Counter(chain.from_iterable(d.items() for d in dicts))
result = {k:[n,v] for ((k,v),n) in result.items()}

print dict(result)
```

Comment: Thanks! But I need values also (it could be separate dictionary, if it will work faster with such approach).

Comment: Does `result = Counter(chain.from_iterable(d.items() for d in dicts))` satisfy your needs?

Comment: @LA_ : see my 3rd solution above.